# Failed to build flutter app after flutter upgrade to 3.0.2

Tags: android, flutter

Getting this errors after flutter upgrade to 3.0.2

```
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_archive-4.1.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/kineapps/flutterarchive/FlutterArchivePlugin.kt: (370, 58): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error(p0: String, p1: String?, p2: Any?): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result

.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_archive-4.1.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/kineapps/flutterarchive/FlutterArchivePlugin.kt: (387, 17): 'error' overrides nothing
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Try upgrading flutter_archive package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_archive/versions/5.0.0 It might be the issue

Comment: try "flutter pub cache repair "

Answer (score 0):

The signature of error() has changed and therefore the version of flutter_archive you are using does not work anymore. They override this method in FlutterArchivePlugin.kt.

The developers of flutter_archive have fixed this issue so an update of the plugin should be enough.

Old:

```
fun error(code: String?, msg: String?, details: Any?)
```

New:

```
fun error(code: String, msg: String?, details: Any?)
```